# About $L^{p}$ norms and the Hilbert transform

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

When we are proving $L^{p}$ estimates for the Hilbert transform, we can proceed in the following way:

**Step 1** Prove that $H$ maps $L^{2}$ to $L^{2}$.

**Step 2** Prove that $H$ maps $L^{1}$ to $L^{1}_{weak}$.

**Step 3** Use Marcinkiewicz's interpolation theorem to conclude that $H$ maps $L^{p}$ to $L^{p}$ if $1<p<2$.

**Step 4** Use Riesz's duality to prove that $H$ maps $L^{p}$ to $L^{p}$ if $2<p<\infty$.

I have to questions about Step 4. Assume you have done all previous steps. This is how we proceed: for $2<p<\infty$ and $f\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}),$
\begin{equation}
\|Hf\|_{p} = \displaystyle\sup_{\|g\|_{p^{\prime}}\leq 1}{\left|\int (Hf)g\right|} = \displaystyle\sup_{\|g\|_{p^{\prime}}\leq 1}{\left|\int f(Hg)\right|} \leq \displaystyle\sup_{\|g\|_{p^{\prime}}\leq 1}\|f\|_{p}\|Hg\|_{p^{\prime}} \leq \displaystyle\sup_{\|g\|_{p^{\prime}}\leq 1}C\|f\|_{p}\|g\|_{p^{\prime}}
\end{equation}
So
\begin{equation}
\|Hf\|_{p} \leq C\|f\|_{p}
\end{equation}

In the first inequality above we used a characterization of the $L^{p}$ norm. My first question is, can I use this characterization even if I don't know yet if $Hf\in L^{p}$? Asking in another way, is it possible that $Hf\notin L^{p}$ and $\displaystyle\sup_{\|g\|_{p^{\prime}}\leq 1}{\left|\int (Hf)g\right|}<\infty$?

Second, let take a look at the second equality above. It comes from the following identity that holds for all $f,g\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$:
\begin{equation}
\int (Hf)g = -\int f(Hg)
\end{equation}
I can prove that this still holds for $g\in L^{p^{\prime}}$ (note that $1<p^{\prime}<2$ and we are assuming boundedness in this range) if I know that $\|Hf\|_{p}<\infty$, this is just a density argument using Holder's inequality. The problem is, this is exactly what I am trying to prove, that $\|Hf\|_{p}<\infty$, so I don't understand how you can say that the second inequality holds without assuming that.

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your first question is yes, *because* Lebesgue measure is $\sigma$-finite. But it seems to me that the first question is irrelevant if you look at it right. The right way to look at it is to take all these inequalities as "a priori inequalities", meaning we're restricting everything to a dense subspace.

Say we've proved the inequality for $1<p\le 2$, and suppose $2<p<\infty$. It does look as though we're proving that $||Hf||_p\le c||f||_p$ *before* we have any reason to suppose that there *is* such a thing as $Hf$ for $f\in L^p$. Yes, this is confusing, to say the least.

But don't look at it that way. Assume we've proved the inequality for $1<p\le2$, and assume $2<p<\infty$. Now assume that $f,g\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$. Then there's no problem with existence of $Hf$ or $Hg$, and we see that $$\left|\int(Hf)g\right|=\left|\int f(Hg)\right|\le||f||_p||Hg||_{p'}\le c||f||_p||g||_{p'},\quad f,g\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}).$$Since the Schwarz space is dense in $L^{p'}$that last inequality shows that $$||Hf||_{p}\le c||f||_{p}\quad(f\in\mathcal S(\Bbb R)).$$And now having proved that, the density of the Schwarz space in $L^p$ shows that $H$ has a unique extension to a bounded operator on $L^p$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let me just ask a couple of things more: how does the $\sigma$-finite property of the Lebesgue measure imply that I can use the characterization? Is there any reference where I can read the proof? Second, okay, let us restric the domain of $H$ to $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$. Can I restrict the supremum to all functions $g\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ with $L^{p^{\prime}}$ norm $\leq 1$? I can prove that this is true if I know previously that $Hf$ is in $L^{p}$.

Comment: See Folland. Yes, actually I said so.